# Flat tire keeps occurring while bike is stationary. MYSTERY

Tags: puncture

I keep changing my tube. It get's a hole right near the base of the valve. I've checked the rim, there's nothing sharp. there's nothing sharp in the tire (the hole's on the inside anyhow). and it always happens while just sitting in my garage not while riding and bumping into rocks or such. all of a sudden from what I cannot determine you hear a hissing sound as air starts escaping. The tube was pumped with ~75 psi about 2 weeks ago, and the tire says max 80, min 50. the rim tape is intact.

Please suggest what could be causing these flat tires, why is there a delay from when I stop riding it and 8 hours later between getting a flat.

Comment: How many times has this happened?

Comment: I'd recheck the tire. You may have a bit of wire or similar sharp bit that is embedded. Try taking a cloth and wiping the inside of the tire, couple rounds in each direction, and see if the cloth catches on anything.

Comment: Is the valve centered? Is it bending to one side or the other?

Comment: Of course, if the tire was pumped up 2 weeks ago the pressure is likely below 50.  But one would expect it to need to fall below about 30 for the valve to tear from twisting while riding.

Comment: I saw [this service alert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwP3MroaWxs) for Kenda/Sunlite 700cx35-40 Schrader tubes a few days ago.  The stem seal vulcanization is weak, leading to separation from the rest of the tube.  Are you getting a puncture, or is it peeling?  Also might want to rub a cotton swab around the inside of the stem hole on your rim to see if it gets caught on any burs.

Comment: Have you successfully ridden this wheel in the past and this is a new phenomenon? Presta or shrader valves, does the hole in the rim match the valve size?

Comment: Another possibility is the temperature of your garage?

Comment: Could it be that you have a spoke poking at your inner tube? Is the rim tape properly installed?

Comment: It's not an answer, but a good point thou. Try to swap tires rear vs front, and see what will flat / puncture.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the puncture on the tube. That would greatly help.

Comment: The "mystery" seems to be shifting to why the OP is ignoring all the follow-up questions.  I'm betting we don't hear back until he has yet another flat...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my bike. The manufacturer had made the rims too deep and it was causing the tube to conform to the odd extra "U" shape when pumped up. It took a while to figure out why I was going through so many tubes.

Check with your manufacturer / retailer. I got mine replaced free of charge.

Perhaps your rims have an abnormality near the valve hole.